# Django Logout View Type Error with python 2.7.11

Tags: django, python-2.7, logout

I have a logout view:

```
class LogoutView(generic.RedirectView):
    url = reverse_lazy("home")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return super(self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And on the line `return super(self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)` there is the following error:

```
must be type, not LogoutView
```

How do I fix this error?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `super()` passing the type as the first parameter, you can see more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

So update the return statement to:

`return super(LogoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Thanks for the help.